# How to delete a row from attribute table on QGIS1.8.0

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Is it possible to a delete row from attribute table!?
I can delete from selecting feature.

I encountered invisible polygon. I could not select feature.
Thus, I would like to know how to delete from row.

If possible,Let me know!!

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can delete features by selecting them in the attribute table.

1. Make the layer editable.
2. Open the attributes table and identify the feature in question in the table
3. Click on the row number on the left-hand side (the row turns blue)
4. Click the delete button at the bottom of the dialog box

Having said that - if your feature is invisible, there might be some corruption in the data.

Comment: Jst in case the steps won't work: Some data drivers only allow reading the data. This makes editing impossible. In that case, you should export the data to shapefile, and add that to canvas for editing.

Comment: I counld delete from attribute following with your instruction!Thank you so much!!